# Python urllib2 unfinished download file

Tags: python, download, urllib2

This script downloads a file from a website and in large files there is a problem because lost packets cause stop downloading... Here is the code:

```
def download(self):

    adres = r"http://example.com/100_MbFile.zip"
    local = adres.split('/')[-1].split('#')[0].split('?')[0]

    try:
        print "Przygotowanie do zapisania pliku " + local
        u = urllib2.urlopen(adres)
        f = open(local, 'wb')
        meta = u.info()
        file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
        print("Downloading: {0} Bytes: {1}".format(adres, file_size))

        file_size_dl = 0
        block_sz = 8192
        while True:
            buffer = u.read(block_sz)
            if not buffer:
                break

            file_size_dl += len(buffer)
            f.write(buffer)
            p = float(file_size_dl) / file_size
            status = r"{0}  [{1:.2%}]".format(file_size_dl, p)
            status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
            sys.stdout.write(status)


        if file_size_dl == file_size:
            f.close()
```

Any ideas how to download large files?

Comment: Have you checked out this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979435/a-multi-part-threaded-downloader-via-python

Answer (score 0):

for downloading and saving files in Python 2, you have a few options...

you could use `urllib`:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve

this essentially does what you were attempting:

```
import urllib

filename = '100_MbFile.zip'
url = 'http://example.com/' + filename

urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

... or you could use `urllib2`, and specify a chunk size to read (like in your example code).

```
import urllib2

filename = '100_MbFile.zip'
url = 'http://example.com/' + filename

req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
block_sz = 8192
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = req.read(block_sz)
        if not chunk:
            break
        f.write(chunk)
```

- note: in Python 3, the standard library has been re-organized and both of these are available in `urllib.request`:
  http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: This solutions not work because retrieval it's incomplete...  I have looked for solution for large files.

Comment: this should work on *any* size file (even larger than you can buffer in memory on your machine).  If you don't get the complete content, there is something wrong with your service.